# AdBannerView & popover: just hide?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller, iad, adbannerview

In my iPad app I have a AdBannerView, and I need to present a popover.

If I do so it throws the warning saying that the banner could be hidden: infact even if the banner is not actually hidden, the user can NOT click on it, because the tap would be intercepted by the popover (so the tap will have the effect of closing the popover, not opening the advertisement).

It turns out that making the ad hidden b4 presenting the popover, and show it again after the popover is gone, removes the warning. (of course it does, the ad is not visible anymore!)

But, how does this work? If I hide the banner and then I show it again, do I still get the revenue for it?

And is there any better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just ignore the warning. 
If the Ad is fully visible it should be no problem.

Comment: So you wouldn't even go for the .hidden = YES ?

Comment: I had this warning in one of my apps, too. I ignored it and the app was approved without a problem.

Comment: @Abramodj: i agree with pre, had the same situation.

Comment: I'm sure it will be approved! I was wondering about the revenues from the ad

Comment: I think it has to be visible for 30s or so to count as an impression. You won't get revenue from it if you hide it or if it thinks it's hidden.